# Reversal of the psychological arrow of time on the contraction of the universe

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, time, universe

In Brief History of Time, it says that the people living in a contracting phase (although unsuitable for living or even existence itself, but lets assume) would remember the future but not the past. But why is that necessary? Why not just contract the universe and let the psychological arrow flow it's way?

Comment: That part of book is talking about a hypothetical entropy reversed universe. The book says: *Suppose, however, that God decided that the universe should finish up in a state of high order but that it didn’t matter what state it started in. At early times the universe would probably be in a disordered state. This would mean that disorder would decrease with time.* Hawking then argues that this would mean the arrow of time was reversed. However this is (a) purely hypothetical and (b) unproven speculation.

Comment: As I understand it, there is strong doubt that the arrow of time has anything to do with the second law of thermodynamics. Also, I always thought, if you remembered the future but not the past, wouldn't you just reverse you understanding of what these words mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He didn't say that – or rather, he said it and then said it was wrong.

By definition, the thermodynamic arrow of time points in the direction of higher entropy; the psychological arrow points in the direction where we *don't* remember things; and the cosmological arrow points in the direction where the universe is larger.

He argues that the thermodynamic and psychological arrows always point in the same direction.

Then he says "At first, I believed that disorder would decrease when the
universe recollapsed" – i.e., he believed that the thermodynamic and cosmological arrows also always point in the same direction. That would imply that the psychological arrow also reverses direction when the expansion reverses into contraction.

A page later he says "I realized that I had made a mistake: the no boundary condition implied that disorder would in fact continue to increase during the contraction." In other words, the thermodynamic and psychological arrows don't reverse when the cosmological arrow reverses. They just "flow their way" as you put it.

Comment: Does that mean that we could in fact continue the psychological arrow of time as it is today, even when the universe contracts, with the thermodynamic arrow still increasing (entropy can be further increased to equilibrium allowing memories of past to be formed)? Because unless universe has reached equilibrium state, entropy should go on increasing, allowing memory formation, and thus the mere contraction of the universe should have no effect on the psychological arrow of time